# Monitor creation of a window (HWND)

Tags: c, windows, monitor, hwnd

I would like to Monitor the creation of windows (HWND) in C.

I'd like to know if there's some kind of event that the WINAPI provides to handle the creation of a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned only with top-level windows, you can use [`SetWindowHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) to register a [`ShellProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644991.aspx) and watch for `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED`.  If you need notification of the creation of *any* window, you can use a [`CallWndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644975.aspx) and watch for `WM_CREATE` messages.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to proceed to Set a Windows Hook with a DLL. I know you need to use a DLL for hooks that aren't WH_KEYBOARD or WH_MOUSE but I don't know how to do that exactly.

Comment: @SBSTP:  Unfortunately, I do not have an example that I can share.  I can try to hunt one down...