# How to hook the repaint event of screen (make a middle level of screen) on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, mirroring, setwindowshookex

I'm wondering how to render Screen as a middle level.

that is, I can produce the screen HDC after every repaint of screen, and before the screen is actually display on monitor.

for example, the magnifier utility of Window 7. you can see the content under the magnifier window, how does it made?

Comment: Screens don't repaint, windows do.  You get the magnifier effect by using a timer and using BitBlt() to make a screenshot.  Make it tick at every, say, 50 msec and it looks smooth.

Comment: but in that way I will capture my window myself. What I want is get content just **under** my window so as other region. EDIT: I have found on WinVista/7, there are a Magnification API to made this, thank you all the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps

1. Identify visible windows using [EnumWindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246444/how-can-i-get-enumwindows-to-list-all-windows)
2. Listen on window creation to update the set of visible windows, [Shell Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033465/9437799)
3. Listen on WM_PAINT messages with a [Message Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), where the Desktop has a dedicated [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669111/how-do-i-get-the-window-handle-of-the-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, the specific issue is in capturing the screen while treating the capturing application as if it were transparent.

A solution for this was introduced in Windows 10 Version 2004 via the `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE` constant to the [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) API. The effect of setting this on a window is that screen captures (using `BitBlt()` or [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture)) will contain whatever is underneath this window.

No hooking into the desktop compositor is required to make this work.