# How to launch my C# application when any application starts in Windows 8?

Tags: c#

I want to launch my application, like the windows security prompt, before any application is launched in Windows 8.
Is there any event handler, which gets notified whenever any application is launched?

My use Case : I want an App similar to a child lock(Lets call it myCustomApp).
When any user runs a game(say Solitare), i want myCustomApp to check the process name, and kill the process immediately.

P.S. : i am quite new to programming.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any event handler, which gets notified whenever any application is launched?

Yes: you get use WMI events to detect new instances of `Win32_Process`.

But these are created with process creation, not before.

Doing something between the call to `ProcessCreate` that creates the new process, and the process actually being created is going to be, at best hard (you might need to do it in the kernel), but quite possibly impossible.

Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? This really does sound like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

**Edit:**

- The term you need to use is *hook*: the interception of some operation on windows. Eg. "[Is it possible to hook the creation of windows globally so I can control where the windows are placed on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7033356/67392)"
- There is a direct way in the kernel: [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- There are helpers in user mode (eg. [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)), but these require injected your code into each process (which anti-malware tools are likely to object to).

*But* you should still start out by looking for better approaches to you underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My use Case : I want an App similar to a child lock(Lets call it myCustomApp).
When any user runs a game(say Solitare), i want myCustomApp to check the process name, and kill the process immediately.

P.S. : i am quite new to programming.

Comment: @SurajKhurana: Group Policy already has the ability to block certain executables (by various criteria, including name) from being run.

Comment: Hi @Richard, 
Actually i was giving an example.I want to 'hook' my application to other applications.