# How to use the Windows IShellWindows::OnCreated API?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

I need my app to be notified of any file Explorer events like open, close, navigate, focus, click etc.

I exploring `IShellWindows` interface for this. I get how to use APIs like `_NewEnum`, `get_Count` etc. However, how to use `OnCreated`, `OnActivated`, `OnNavigate` APIs are quite unclear. It seems these are callbacks which should be invoked when the corresponding events occur. But there is no documentation around how to set-up the callbacks. Am I missing something?

Comment: These parts of IShellWindows are used to gather different types of "shell windows" (like Explorer windows and Internet Explorer windows, etc.) under one common umbrella. So, one's supposed to call IShellWindows::Register to register a new window (and get a referencing cookie) and call OnCreated, etc. to instruct the Shell it's been created whatever all that means. But it's not meant to be used as events *from* Explorer. Look here for how to handle two events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974072/403671 For folder events, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140922-00/?p=44013